# Prove that every orthogonal matrix $(Q^T Q = I)$ has determinant $1$ or $-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, determinant, matrix-equations, orthogonality

A matrix $Q$ is orthogonal if $Q^TQ=I$. I want to prove that if $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $|Q|=\pm 1$.
My try is :
$$ |Q||Q| = |I|$$
$$|Q||Q| = 1$$

Comment: $$ |Q^T| = |Q|$$

Comment: Indeed that is the proof

Comment: but here I see the product of the two orthogonal matrices

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. You are trying to prove that $\mathrm {det}(Q)=\pm 1$ if $Q$ is orthogonal, right?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Then you did it correctly. Just to flesh it all out $\mathrm {det}(Q^TQ)=\mathrm {det}(I)\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q^T)\mathrm {det}(Q)=1\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q)\mathrm {det}(Q)=1\Rightarrow (\mathrm {det}(Q))^2=1\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q)=\pm 1$.

Comment: why (det(Q)^2) = det(Q)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140154/discussion-between-hackr-and-ramanujans-alkhazarim).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The proof is indeed correct, with the correct identification that $\mathrm{det}(Q^T)=\mathrm{det}(Q)$. As requested in chat, a fleshed out proof of the same

\begin{align*}
Q^TQ=I&\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q^TQ)=\mathrm {det}(I)\\ &\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q^T)\mathrm {det}(Q)=1\\&\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q)\mathrm {det}(Q)=1\\&\Rightarrow (\mathrm {det}(Q))^2=1\\&\Rightarrow \mathrm {det}(Q)=\pm 1
\end{align*}